# How to get private preferences from a service?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-service

When I run my Activity I use to get the preferences object like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and I'd like to get this object from the Application's service as well; unfortunately the Service class doesn't provide the getPreferences method, but only the getSharedPreferences() method; which parameters should I use to get the same object?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you only use one `SharedPreferences` in your application, you can simply get it via `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

BTW. `SharedPreferences` doesn't work across different processes.